# docker automatically commit and push

Tags: bash, docker

I'm trying to setup a GUI application in docker to use it on different computers with the exact same configuration. The container is working but I always have to commit and push the changes manually.

Is there a way to automatically commit and push the changes of the docker container after the container was stopped (by closing the application).

Thanks for helping,
Flo

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a tool which does that automatically, but you could write one. Docker emits events when containers stop, so you could have a process that subscribes to those events (or a cron job that occasionally polls for them) and when it detects a closed container (maybe with your own naming convention?), it could automatically `docker commit` and tag.

The events are available via `docker events` ([docs](http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/events/)), and the [Docker Remote REST API](http://docs.docker.com/reference/api/docker_remote_api/#docker-events).

Comment: After some research I found that somebody already did wrote a tool for this: https://github.com/discordianfish/docker-spotter I'll try it in the next couple of days.